# How to calculate mean adjusted abnormal return

Tags: r, loops, return, mean

I would like to calculate mean adjusted returns for several companies. 
I have monthly data. I would like to calculate the rolling mean for the last 12 month. After that I need to subtract the rolling mean from the monthly return.

At first I used `quantmod` and `lapply` for calculating the returns:

```
library(quantmod)

stocks=new.env()

startDate=as.Date("2008-07-31")

endDate=as.Date("2019-06-30")

tickers=c("ADS.DE","DAI.DE","BMW.DE")

getSymbols(tickers,src="yahoo",env=stocks,from=startDate,to=endDate)

stocksL=as.list(stocks)

returns.daily=lapply(stocksL, function(x) diff(log(Cl(x))))

returns.montly=lapply(returns.daily, apply.monthly, sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

In the next step I have to calculate the rolling mean for the last 12 month for each month. My estimation period is from 2009-07-31 to 2019-06-30.
After that I have to subtract the rolling mean from the return for each month.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rollapply()` function. Assuming you want to calculate the mean return per annum at every month, the code would be:

```r
library(zoo)

returns.rolling=lapply(returns.montly, 
                       function(x) rollapply(x, width = 12, FUN = mean))

aR = Map("-",returns.montly, lapply(returns.rolling, stats::lag))
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems to work. Now I have two lists: returns.monthly and returns.rolling. The second step is to calculate the abnormal return. I have to substract returns.rolling from returns.monthly. I have tried funcion map: `aR=Map("-",returns.monthly,returns.rolling)`. The problem is that R substracts the values for the same month. I have to substract the previous month. For example for 2009-07-31: 2009-07-31 (from returns.monthly) - 2009-06-30 (from returns.rolling).  How can I select the previous month?

Comment: I updated the answer to with your Map code, but used the `stats::lag()` function to ensure you subtract the previous month's rolling return.